# Hide/Remove ContentType from a SP List with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I am creating a SP List via REST API, and after the list has been created I'm adding a custom ContentType to that list.
So, my custom ContentType should be a default CT on that List.

I've already tried this but it doesn't work, probably my contentType has to be an object..

```
let dfd = new $.Deferred();
let targetUrl = config.App + subsiteTitle;
let clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(targetUrl);

if (clientContext !== undefined && clientContext !== null) {
  let web = clientContext.get_web();
  let listCollection = web.get_lists();
  let list = listCollection.getByTitle(listTitle);
  let contentType = list.get_contentTypes().getById('0x01');
  contentType.deleteObject();

  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
      dfd.resolve(this);
    }),
    Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args) {
      console.log('Failed to remove content type ' + args.get_message());
    })
  )
}

return dfd.promise();
```

Does anyone know how to hide or remove 'Item' ContentType from that List with JavaScript, or to set my custom ContentType as default, doesn't matter if it is via REST API or JSOM?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example two actions are missing:

- adding content type into list, [`SP.ContentTypeCollection.addExistingContentType` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246551.aspx) could be utilized for that purpose
- in order to set a specific content as a default one, in needs to be
  specified as a first using [`SP.Folder.uniqueContentTypeOrder` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee548689(v=office.14).aspx)

**Example**

```
let ctx = new SP.ClientContext(targetUrl);

let ct = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_contentTypes().getById(contentTypeId);
let targetList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
let listContentTypes = targetList.get_contentTypes();
listContentTypes.addExistingContentType(ct); //1. add content type into list

var folder = targetList.get_rootFolder();
ctx.load(folder, 'ContentTypeOrder');
ctx.load(ct);
executeQuery(ctx)
    .then(() => {

        //2. set added content type as a default one   
        let ctIdList = folder.get_contentTypeOrder().sort((x,y) =>{ 
            return x.get_stringValue().indexOf(contentTypeId) != -1 ? -1 : y.get_stringValue().indexOf(contentTypeId) != -1 ? 1 : 0; 
        });
        folder.set_uniqueContentTypeOrder(ctIdList);
        folder.update();
        return executeQuery(ctx);
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Done!");
    })
```

where

```
function executeQuery(context) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            resolve();
        }, function (sender, args) {
            reject(args);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the code below to set the custom content type to default. Note: Modify the "listname" to your list name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ChangeContentTypeOrder, "sp.js");
function ChangeContentTypeOrder(){
    var listname="CustomList";
    var c = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var folder = c.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listname).get_rootFolder();
    c.load(folder, 'ContentTypeOrder');
    c.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        folder.set_uniqueContentTypeOrder(folder.get_contentTypeOrder().reverse()); 
        folder.update();
        c.executeQueryAsync();
    }); 
}
</script>
```

We can set it using SharePoint UI in list settings.

[image]